# Changing Visual Studio settings file at runtime

Tags: .net, visual-studio

I wonder if I add a setting file to my Visual Studio (WinForms) project if it is possible to change a setting value without needing to rebuild the project?
Beside App.Config I want to be able to change specific setting in another setting file. But I don't want to recompile the code since I'm in production.

Comment: Why don't you just add it to App.Config? It's explicitly designed for that purpose.

Comment: That is the point, for some reason the team don't want to do that.

Comment: Put a bounty on the question if you aren't happy with the answer you got.  Also the team is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

We've created a new configuration class that reads from a separate configuration file (the path to which is specified in app.config).  This class works just like ConfigurationManager, but it auto-refreshes its configuration data every X minutes.

This lets us change a configuration setting in our website without effectively restarting the app pool.

Make sense?

Comment: Yes. But the problem I'm having is that it seems that settings files become embedded at build time. I have played around with build setting on the setting file. When I choose for example content the setting file is not embedded anymore but the change in settings doesn’t affect the application. Even if I restart the application.

Comment: Set the build action of your app.config to None and "Copy to output directory" to None.  You are explicitly telling VS to embed the config file into the application.  Don't do that.

Comment: Also, there may be a bit of confusion here.  The config file you would change is the name of the executable plus '.config'.  For example, say you have yodaj007_is_awesome.exe.  The config file would then be yodaj007_is_awesome.exe.config.  Change THAT file.

Comment: Nope! The other config have the name let say "x".